# WCF. Patterns. SQL Server

Tags: wcf, design-patterns

I will develop a WCF service. The service will get data from SQL Server.

What patterns I should use to separate access code to SQL Server and other code. In future I am planning to change access logic to SQL Server (LINQ to SQL or ADO.NET or Entity Framework).

Comment: @Sergii: please don't ask the same question twice.

Comment: @John Saunders: But It is another question. This about pattern.
Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be able to replace the data access logic you will have to isolate it from the rest of the application. I think the "Repository" pattern could help.